# Hyper V access to remote offices

Tags: hyper-v

We are looking to consolidating 3 physical servers to 3VM on 1 host. Currently, we have 2 remote offices that use a VPN and connect with Citrix. THe remote office desktops are configured as a workgroup. 
Are there any Hyper V solutions to allow the remote offices to connect or should we be using another server at the remote offices?

Comment: Agreed, your Hyper V guests, whilst having a different architecture, will appear the the rest of the network as 3 separate servers, in the same manner as they have always done. What problems are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be worried that moving your servers from physical machines to virtual machines will somehow change their behavior as observed by client machines.  This isn't true.

Virtual machines behave as physical machines on the network, assuming you set up the virtual network switches correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd need to change anything at the remote site - they should just work the same or have I misunderstood?